# How write the ignore dupkey command in unix?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, on-duplicate-key

I know that in oracle the is a way to write to ignore the dupkey, something like

```
/*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(tab, index_tab) */
```

Is there a way to do the same thing but with unix commands? I think there's a way with `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE` but i'm not sure and i don't know how do it. Thanks

Comment: Is the data in a file, one date per line?

Comment: yes there is. I'm making an insert from a file. But this insert is dynamic and is in more tabs so i can't write the `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index` command. I need something in unix code.

Comment: Can you remove the duplicated rows from the file, f.i. with `sort -u`?

Comment: Sorry maybe i've been not clear. I mean "if during the insert there are some duplicate records ignore and go on". Understand now?

Comment: 1) Can you temporarily disable indexes, remove constraint and load the data? 2) You can create and external table without any constraints, after the load insert into the target table.

Comment: So you are looking for a solution in SQL or SQL*Plus? How about `MERGE` instead of `INSERT`?

Comment: Looking for SQL*Plus solution. Mmh how can i use `MERGE`?